# Using window.open with blob files not working with Cordova or Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, electron, localforage

I am building my Apps with JavaScript using Cordova and Electron for mobile and desktop apps. In my App, I have a offline feature, where you can download content which is saved using localforage. It works great to show my images, audios, videos and so on.

However, I also have files in the app for users to download (zip, pdf, ...), by using the window.open command, which works as long as I'm using the file's url from the server. But when I use the offline feature and use the blob-url from my localforage, the app doesn't react at all to my onClick event. It doesn't open and also showing no errors in the console.
In the browser though it works just fine, whether it's the blob-url or server-url.

I first used `window.open(src, '_blank');`, but also tried to remove the `_blank` attribute with no luck.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please your code.